# odoo - NameError name is not defined

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to create a field based on how it has been done in the core sale.py file. But it gives me

> NameError: name '_amount_all_wrapper' is not defined.

My **sale.py** code:

```
class SaleOrder(osv.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'

_columns = {
    'xx_delivery_date': fields.date(string='Delivery date'),
    #'xx_payment_method': fields.selection([('visa', 'Visa'),
    #                                       ('cash', 'Cash')],
    #                                      string='Payment method'),
    'xx_payment_method': fields.many2one('xx.payment.method',
                                         string='Payment method'),
    'xx_insurance_type': fields.many2one('xx.insurance.type', string='Insurance'),
    #test to move line
    'amount_insurance': fields.function(_amount_all_wrapper, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Insurance',
        store={
            'sale.order': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
            'sale.order.line': (_get_order, ['price_unit', 'tax_id', 'discount', 'product_uom_qty'], 10),
        },
        multi='sums', help="Amount untaxed plus insurance percentage."),
}

def _amount_all_wrapper(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    """ Wrapper because of direct method passing as parameter for function fields """
    return self._amount_all(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)
```

the **error** refers to the `'amount_insurance': fields.function(_amount_all_wrapper, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Insurance',` line

Since this is exactly the same as they did and i can't find any reference to `_amount_all_wrapper` in their code except the method, I don't really get whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition to _amount_all_wrapper needs to exist before you start to reference it. Adding self will not work as the object is not yest created when this line of code is being executed. Yous would have been getting this error even before any code execution, while the interpreter is loading the script and creating all the class definitions. thus it is necessary to have the object defined before actually referencing it.

so just move the code around like this:

```
class SaleOrder(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def _amount_all_wrapper(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        """ Wrapper because of direct method passing as parameter for function fields """
        return self._amount_all(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)

    _columns = {
        'xx_delivery_date': fields.date(string='Delivery date'),
        #'xx_payment_method': fields.selection([('visa', 'Visa'),
        #                                       ('cash', 'Cash')],
        #                                      string='Payment method'),
        'xx_payment_method': fields.many2one('xx.payment.method',
                                             string='Payment method'),
        'xx_insurance_type': fields.many2one('xx.insurance.type', string='Insurance'),
        #test to move line
        'amount_insurance': fields.function(_amount_all_wrapper, digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'), string='Insurance',
            store={
                'sale.order': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
                'sale.order.line': (_get_order, ['price_unit', 'tax_id', 'discount', 'product_uom_qty'], 10),
            },
            multi='sums', help="Amount untaxed plus insurance percentage."),
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this always the case with methods in Python?

Comment: not always. Inside function definitions, you can refer the objects that you will be defining later. this is because a function object is created while parsing the code but its body is not executed. but when you create a class object, its attributes are created and initialized while parsing. Thus any referenced objects need to be defined before hand.